# Video element in Flexbox (css) not centered in IE only

Tags: css, flexbox, html5-video, vertical-alignment

My demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tk14jbry/

Result as expected in Chrome / Safari / MS Edge (yes!):
[image]

I assume the problem is my structure:

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <video width="320" height="240">...
  </video>
</div>
```

How can I make IE 11 (don't care about below) work?

(I do not want to add another element between .flexbox and video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position: absolute;` on your your video element in your CSS to `position: relative;`

You have the following inside a flex container.  The absolute positioning of that element is not going to allow the container's alignment properties to work correctly.

```
#Kurzfilm video {
  margin: 0 auto;  
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute; 
}
```

Change to:

```
#Kurzfilm video {
  position: relative; 
}
```

`margin: 0 auto;` isn't necessary to center it since you've set the alignment properties on the container.  `display: inline-block;` is also unnecessary.

Following is a screen snapshot from IE 11 on Windows 10 running in Browserstack:

[image]

Comment: That works for all BUT Safari, the video is not displayed at all in Safari.

Comment: It's because by taking the absolute positioning off of it, your overlay is now on top of the video.  It's there, it's just underneath the overlay.

Comment: Yep relative positioning seems to address the layering issue across the board.  I'll update my answer.